# CMake: How to add add subdirectory as last step

Tags: cmake

I have this file structure:

root
  |
  +--API
  |    |
  |    +-CMakeFiles.txt
  |
  +--gtest
         |
         +-CMakeFiles.txt

In root, I have a CMakeFiles.txt that contains:
add_subdirectory(gtest)
add_subdirectory(API)

API has dependencies on files genreated by gtest. How can I get it so that API waits until gtest is completely finished building before executing API's CMakeList? Is there some sort of delay I can add?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try find_library(SOME_VAR gtest) in API CMakeLists.txt. API will be building after building gtest.